# How to avoid UI freezing while typing highlighting text?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm working on JSON text editor analog with highlighting syntax support.
I'm using DevExpress RichEditControl, where override ISyntaxHighlightService(using class, which implements this).

After getting pretty JSON text at the view highlighter starts working permanently, searching for different tokens, classifying them to highlight with concrete color. So, searching mechanism works too long if there are more than 300 lines of text, and it causes freezing UI while typing text.

I think I should run that things in other thread, but I get errors, related to "control is in another thread"...

The last thing I've tried, was invoking that method 1 or 2 per second, using DispatherTimer, to make the problem less enoying, but it still doesn't work as easy as in popular text editors because of delay.

So, what could you offer? May be there are alternative methods for coloring syntax? Or I can use side text editor control with such functions, instead of RichEditControl? May be it's easy to be reached, using converters and XAML?

ISyntaxHighLightService implemetation:

```
    public class CustomSyntaxHighlightService : ISyntaxHighlightService
{
    Document document;

    Regex _numberString = new Regex(@"(\d+\W\d+)|[\d]+| (.*?)");
    Regex _quotedString = new Regex("\"([^\"]*)\"[:]");

    public CustomSyntaxHighlightService(Document document)
    {
        this.document = document;

        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatherExecute);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatherExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<SyntaxHighlightToken> JSONTokens = ParseTokens();
        document.ApplySyntaxHighlight(JSONTokens);
    }

    public void ForceExecute()
    {

    }

    public void Execute()
    {

    }

    private List<SyntaxHighlightToken> ParseTokens()
    {
        List<SyntaxHighlightToken> tokens = new List<SyntaxHighlightToken>();
        DocumentRange[] ranges = null;

        ranges = document.FindAll(_quotedString).GetAsFrozen() as DocumentRange[];
        for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
        {
            tokens.Add(CreateToken(ranges[i].Start.ToInt(), ranges[i].End.ToInt(), Color.FromArgb(207, 101, 239)));
        }

        // When I try to add such code block with another token string I get an error...

        //ranges = document.FindAll(_anotherString).GetAsFrozen() as DocumentRange[];
        //for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
        //{
        //  tokens.Add(CreateToken(ranges[i].Start.ToInt(), ranges[i].End.ToInt(), Color.FromArgb(207, 101, 239)));
        //}

        ranges = document.FindAll(_numberString).GetAsFrozen() as DocumentRange[];
        for (int j = 0; j < ranges.Length; j++)
        {
            if (!IsRangeInTokens(ranges[j], tokens))
            {
                tokens.Add(CreateToken(ranges[j].Start.ToInt(), ranges[j].End.ToInt(), Color.DeepSkyBlue));
            }
        }

        tokens.Sort(new SyntaxHighlightTokenComparer());

        tokens = CombineWithPlainTextTokens(tokens);
        return tokens;
    }

    List<SyntaxHighlightToken> CombineWithPlainTextTokens(List<SyntaxHighlightToken> tokens)
    {
        List<SyntaxHighlightToken> result = new List<SyntaxHighlightToken>(tokens.Count * 2 + 1);
        int documentStart = document.Range.Start.ToInt();
        int documentEnd = document.Range.End.ToInt();
        if (tokens.Count == 0)
        {
            result.Add(CreateToken(documentStart, documentEnd, Color.Black));
        }
        else
        {
            SyntaxHighlightToken firstToken = tokens[0];
            if (documentStart < firstToken.Start)
            {
                result.Add(CreateToken(documentStart, firstToken.Start, Color.Black));
            }
            result.Add(firstToken);

            for (int i = 1; i < tokens.Count; i++)
            {
                SyntaxHighlightToken token = tokens[i];
                SyntaxHighlightToken prevToken = tokens[i - 1];
                if (prevToken.End != token.Start)
                {
                    result.Add(CreateToken(prevToken.End, token.Start, Color.Black));
                }

                result.Add(token);
            }

            SyntaxHighlightToken lastToken = tokens[tokens.Count - 1];
            if (documentEnd > lastToken.End)
            {
                result.Add(CreateToken(lastToken.End, documentEnd, Color.Black));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private bool IsRangeInTokens(DocumentRange range, List<SyntaxHighlightToken> tokens)
    {
        return tokens.Any(t => IsIntersect(range, t));
    }

    bool IsIntersect(DocumentRange range, SyntaxHighlightToken token)
    {
        int start = range.Start.ToInt();
        if (start >= token.Start && start < token.End)
        {
            return true;
        }

        int end = range.End.ToInt() - 1;
        if (end >= token.Start && end < token.End)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (start < token.Start && end >= token.End)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    SyntaxHighlightToken CreateToken(int start, int end, Color foreColor)
    {
        SyntaxHighlightProperties properties = new SyntaxHighlightProperties();
        properties.ForeColor = foreColor;
        return new SyntaxHighlightToken(start, end - start, properties);
    }

    public class SyntaxHighlightTokenComparer : IComparer<SyntaxHighlightToken>
    {
        public int Compare(SyntaxHighlightToken x, SyntaxHighlightToken y)
        {
            return x.Start - y.Start;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I've understood the idea about cancellation token, but I don't know how to realize it right. Now I have got static class for token:

```
public static class CTTest
{
    public static CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public static CancellationToken Token = CancellationTokenSource.Token;

    public static void SetNewTokenValues()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Token = CancellationTokenSource.Token;
    }
}
```

And I use it here:

```
    void ParseAndHighLight(CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            List<SyntaxHighlightToken> JSONTokens = ParseTokens();

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { document.ApplySyntaxHighlight(JSONTokens); }));
        }
        else
        {
            CTTest.SetNewTokenValues();
            ForceExecute();
        }
    }

    public void ForceExecute()
    {
        Execute();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        t = new Task(() => ParseAndHighLight(CTTest.Token));
        t.Start();
    }
```

Cancelling when text changes:

```
    private void xParsedRichEditControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CTTest.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
```

Comment: You should create a task with a cancellation token for handling the search, and when new data is entered, cancel the previous task an execute it again with the new search.

Comment: @Cleptus, could you help me?

Comment: You are not creating a task and passing it the cancelation token, you are manually creating a new thread. Check and try [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)